# Hewlett-Packard ScanJet 2200c on Scientific Linux 6.1 64bit

Tags: scanner

I have a:

```
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 03f0:0605 Hewlett-Packard ScanJet 2200c
```

Scanner plugged in via USB to my notebook.

When I launch this command (no matter that I use it with a normal user or root, does the same):

```
scanimage --format=tiff --resolution=150 --mode=color > a.tiff
```

The scanner just waits for ~30 sec then starts actually scanning, but it stops after going about ~8cm's.. (so it's scanning just the ~1/3 part of an A/4 paper..) but the scanned part looks good. So the problem is that why doesn't this scanner scans a full A4 paper size? 

I can't find relevant logs..

UPDATE: I wanted to try out the scanner on a Win7Pro64bit machine.. I didn't found any drivers to it :D

Comment: So this scanner is not supported by RedHat or what? :(

Comment: http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/sane-devel/2012-May/thread.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanimage  -l 0 -t 0 -x 215 -y 297 --format=tiff --resolution=150 --mode=color > output.tiff
```

it works! (the default scan size wasn't A4..)

but it's really slow.. it tooked 1:56 to scan a A4 paper..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking for some specific configuration in /etc/sane.d  ?

On Windows 7 you can use VueScan to make your scanner working.